# Java image with double value pixel

Tags: java, image, double, pixel

Actually I'm working with BufferedImages, that provide me pixel values in **int** type.

Do you know a Java object to represent an image that the pixel value in **double** or **float** type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what your end goal is, but you could look into [java.awt.image.ColorModel](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorModel.html)
. Either that or you could do your processing on a float[][]/double[][] and then round if you need to do something with your BufferedImage.

Answer (score 1):

I do know of an implementation off the top of my head, but you can use the SampleModel/WritableRaster to access bands independently and create your own backing however you like. It likely won't be much fun though. Although, I'd question the "access component (??) as a double/float" requirement (unless you're doing something fun like OpenGL 8-bit floats ... which don't map to Java floats anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java Advanced Imaging API (JAI).

JAI introduces two new data classes, which extend the Java 2D `DataBuffer` image data class: `DataBufferFloat` and `DataBufferDouble`.

http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai1_0_1guide-unc/J2D-concepts.doc.html#52401